# How to construct an efficient PostgreSQL index for a conditional date query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I'm trying to query a large database of ~10 million rows, to find all rows with a timestamp above a certain date or with a boolean flag set to false, like:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mytable WHERE (NOT fresh OR created IS NULL OR created <= '2021-1-1');
```

This query was taking an hour to run, but isn't too complex, so I tried creating an index for it like:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY mytable_fresh_created ON mytable (fresh, created ASC) WHERE fresh = false;
```

but this has made virtually no improvement on performance. And running `EXPLAIN` shows a sequential scan:

```
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=18641642.51..18641642.52 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Gather  (cost=18641642.29..18641642.50 rows=2 width=8)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=18640642.29..18640642.30 rows=1 width=8)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..18629381.98 rows=4504126 width=4)
                     Filter: ((NOT fresh) OR (created IS NULL) OR (created <= '2021-1-1'::timestamp with time zone))
```

so it doesn't even look like the index is even being used.

How do I construct a better index for this type of query?

Comment: The partial index with the predicate `fresh = false` is not useful for your query since it does not include all the rows you want to aggregate.

Comment: What estimate percentage of the rows you expect the predicate `NOT fresh OR created IS NULL OR created <= '2021-1-1'` to select?

Comment: Hmm, first things first... You description doesn't necessarily fit the query... You wrote "a timestamp above a certain date **and** with a boolean flag set to false" (emphasis: me), yet in the query there's an `NOT fresh` is connected with `OR`. The way you created the index also rather suggests `AND` and not `OR`. Is the `OR` in the query right?

Comment: The cost estimate and the reported run time are both astonishing for a table with just 10 million rows.  Is it really a billion rows?  Is the table 99% bloat?  And as Sticky Bit says the difference between AND and OR is huge, which one are we really dealing with?

Comment: @stickybit Thanks. That was a typo on my part. The query is correct, but my description  was not.

Answer (score -1):

When you are using `OR` then indexes not using. I recommended using `UNION ALL`. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
WHERE (created <= '2021-01-01'::date)
union all 
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
WHERE (created IS NULL)
```

Comment: Although you're not entirely wrong, you're also not right. 
The `UNION ALL` will most likely cause doubles here. You also will need to provide separate indexes that satisfy the separate `SELECT`s that will be `UNION`'d together otherwise you will have two table scans instead of one! Keep in mind that there is also quite some overhead involved in the `UNION` operation as it removes all doubles. Here we probably can assume the `id` field being unique so just selecting `id` and then `UNION` and then `COUNT(id)` that resultset should work. But it's unlikely to be the fastest approach here.

Comment: Many SQL Developers know that - `UNION ALL` (not `UNION`) gets the best performance than `OR`.  As for duplication this query never gets duplicate data because this condition `(created <= '2021-01-01'::date)` will bet gets only not null and less than `2021-01-01` date. And this condition `(created IS NULL)` will get only null data.

Comment: Agreed, but the query from the OP is about `WHERE (NOT fresh OR created IS NULL OR created <= '2021-1-1')`. You simplified the question so it matches your answer. If the original poster isn't careful and extends the `UNION ALL` logic to the `fresh` column they may run into unexpected trouble. I'd almost say they most likely will.

Comment: Sorry Sorry, I agree with you, you're right. I just didn't pay attention. I don't know your business logic or table design structure. Because sometimes depending on the logic of the program and by making some logical changes we can be not used `OR` commands or other bad performance commands

Comment: Maybe changing the logic of data storing of `fresh` and `created` fields you can not use this condition: `NOT fresh OR created IS NULL`. When I add this `NOT fresh` condition, then maybe we will get duplicate records. But, using the `union` command instead of `union all` so performance will be decreasing. Maybe if you give me more details or more information about fresh and created fields I can help you. I just wanted to explain to you that the index does not work when you use the `OR` command. You must think that how you can write a query without `OR`